# wp get_results - filter unique records

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm having category column in my database, i have to list only unique category by using **`$wpdb->get_results`** how can i filter it? see code below...

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'servicer';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE is_deleted = 0", ARRAY_A);
?>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<?php

foreach($results as $key => $rec)
{
    echo "<li>" . $rec['category'] . "</li>";
}

?>
</ul>
```

current result...

```
cat1
cat1
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat4
```

expected result... `cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(id), * FROM...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Used GROUP BY**

```
$results  = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE 
is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY category", ARRAY_A);
```

**OR 
Used DISTINCT**

```
$results  = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT(category),* FROM 
".$table_name." WHERE is_deleted = 0", ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankur Bhadania