# How to grab only the first result mysql php - multiple queries inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom table in my wordpress database. In the database, I'm showing photo galleries with their own gallery ID's. Each gallery has multiple photos in it, so I might have:

```
image_link: img1.png | upload_id: 47372
image_link: img2.png | upload_id: 47372
image_link: img3.png | upload_id: 47372
image_link: img4.png | upload_id: 373h3
image_link: img5.png | upload_id: 373h3
```

I have code that returns the img id's and links the user to a URL where they can view the gallery:

```
          $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_prefix_photos WHERE user_email='" . $email . "' AND created_date > $sevenDays ORDER BY created_date ASC" );

          ob_start();
          $arr = array();
          foreach ( $results as $result )
          {
            $arr[] = "<div style='border: 1px solid black'><a href='https://mywebsite.com/?photoID=" . $result->upload_id . "'>https://mywebsite.com/?photoID=" . $result->upload_id . "</a></div>";

          }
          $unique_data = array_unique($arr);
          // now use foreach loop on unique data
          foreach($unique_data as $val)
          {
            echo $val;;
          }

          $output = ob_get_clean(); // set the buffer data to variable and clean the buffer
          return $output;
```

Note that it's wrapped in a buffer, because it's inside a Wordpress shortcode, and the foreach stops return on the first result. I also use array_unique() to ensure that all results are unique (there's no need to show the same upload_id twice).

Now, here's the problem: I want to get the first and only the first image_link for each upload_id. When you stick `echo "<br>" . $result->image_link;` inside `foreach ( $results as $result )`, it prints every url that matches the id, and I can't use `array_unique($arr);` again because each img url is unique.

I think I can execute another DB query inside of `foreach($unique_data as $val)`, using $val as the upload_id and grabbing the first result, but is there any way to adjust this so I don't have to? And if I do do that, will it be taxing on the server to run as many DB queries as I have foreach results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this only 30 minutes after asking the question, but I worked on it for hours before asking, so for anyone else who comes across:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_prefix_photos WHERE user_email='" . $email . "' AND created_date > $sevenDays GROUP BY upload_id" );

          ob_start();
          $arr = array();
          foreach ( $results as $result )
          {
            echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black'><a href='https://mywebsite.com/?photoID=" . $result->upload_id . "'>https://mywebsite.com/?photoID=" . $result->upload_id . "</a></div>";
            echo $result->image_link;
          }

          $output = ob_get_clean(); // set the buffer data to variable and clean the buffer
          return $output;
```

I got rid of `array_unique($arr);` and replaced it with `GROUP BY upload_id` in the query, which appears to ensure unique upload_id's and when used with `echo $result->image_link;`, only shows 1 link per unique `upload_id`.

Reference to this questions: [wp get_results - filter unique records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663547/wp-get-results-filter-unique-records)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your query to

"SELECT max(image_link) as image_link,upload_id FROM wp_prefix_photos WHERE user_email='" . $email . "' AND created_date > $sevenDays group by upload_id ORDER BY created_date ASC"

Comment: But doesn't that just limit the ID's I can grab to 1? I don't want one result for the ID's, I want 1 url result PER ID, which in this case is 2–because there are two unique ID's.

Comment: Let me clear, you have different image_linl and unique_id. you want these image_link in one unique_id??? or one image_link for one unique_id???

Comment: Each upload_id is displayed properly. In the DB, each upload_id has multiple image_link's attached to it. I want to show the first one for each upload_id.

Comment: Please try this query also. 
this will get the one image link per unique id.
"SELECT max(image_link) as image_lin,upload_id FROM wp_prefix_photos WHERE user_email='" . $email . "' AND created_date > $sevenDays group by upload_id ORDER BY created_date ASC"